# Cart Drawer won't work [event.preventDefault() won't stop events]

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am building a theme with Liquid and I have followed 2 tutorials to open the cart as a drawer (modal), and I can't get it to work. I think it's related to the events not being prevented accordingly because I get redirected to '/cart' instead of opening the modal (adding the class 'mini-cart-open'.

I would appreciate any help.

https://github.com/icarus/Laboratories-Shopify-Theme/tree/master/snippets

I tried following the tutorials accordingly and ended up just literally copying everything so I later modify it to fit my design but it won't work.